Wrong answers using QGIS Raster Calculator
I am carrying out a simple subtraction of 2 raster layers, both with 1 band using both the raster calculator and GDAL raster calculator tools in QGIS version 3.28.5.
Both rasters are using CRS 4326.
When I use the identify tool on a random pixel, I find a manual subtraction check of the values of the 2 rasters is different to the layer value from using the raster calculation tools. Image below where the first 2 layers are those that were used in the raster calculator process and the 2 below are the results from both tools.
Any reason as to why there is a difference? The project is in a different projection. Would this make a difference?


Are the datasets in the same CRS at the same resolution and with zero offset?

Yes both the same CRS, same resolution and zero offset

And is the result in the source projection or projected, and if projected, how are the values interpolated? Clearly having the project in a different projection does make a difference, and whether the data is interpolated then has math applied or has math applied and then is interpolated will make a difference as well.

The result is in the source projection

And both rasters have same extent?

Origins are slightly different (-2.5939678737287863,53.6634270335632095) & (-2.5940164052971832,53.6634089276498685) and I think that is where the problem may be

Origin needs to be exactly the same.
Use mask extent to create two rasters with identical origins in preparation for raster calculator process.
